# Stop Invisible Label from taking up space

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to stop a label control that is not visible from taking up space on a form?

Answer (score 8):

server side:

```
label.Attributes["style"] = "display:none";
```

or

```
label.Visible = false;
```

or, client-side (css):

```
#label-id { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set it's visibility to hidden through CSS.  Or set it through the code behind to false.  From the code behind a false setting should cause it to not be rendered at all.

Optionally, replace the label with a literal control and only emit something to it when you need to.

Comment: visibility:hidden hides the content but does not treat is as it's not there (the content still takes the same amount of space, it's just not visible).

Comment: Actually I meant display none... Upvoting your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

2 good answers already, so just a couple of notes:

1. Using Visible=false at the server-side is usually better since that will not output any HTML at all, as opposed to CSS which will output it but just hide it.  Unless of course you need it there so you can unhide client-side.
2. The label itself usually doesn't add any space, it is the white-space before/after it that might, so yet another option (if you work in HTML source view 99% of the time like I do) is to remove any white-space before/after the control.  Not as robust as the other options since it could be easy to get that white-space back by mistake (especially if the IDE does it for you while working in design view).  Just thought I'd mention it, since this can be good to know if you want the label VISIBLE but don't want the "extra space".